# N = 25 Queens problem. using the vanilla hill-climbing algorithm

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, computer-science, n-queens

Does anyone know a good approach to solving the N queens problem as {N = 25}, using the vanilla hill-climbing algorithm?

Comment: What is your question exaclty? Hill climbing is a good approach, so your question seems self answered. (Also, since it's your first question, take a look at [ask])

Answer (score 0):

From the [OptaPlanner](https://www.optaplanner.org/) documentation:

[image: hill climbing]

Notice that it doesn't find the optimal solution because it gets stuck in a local optimum.

[image]

YMMV for 25 queens, but you might want to improve it by transforming it into Tabu Search:

[image: tabu search]